# Problema com script Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tenho um script Ajax de pesquisa sem recarregar a página, eu seleciono as taxonomy's para filtrar o conteúdo, e clico em "Search", nisso o formulário de busca desaparece, aparece uma barra de carregamento.
A barra de carregamento desaparece e o conteúdo buscado aparece.
até ai tudo bem, só que, eu preciso que o formulário de busca não desapareça, que a barra de carregamento fique abaixo dela.

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Ultimate WP Query Search Filter
Plugin URI: http://www.9-sec.com/
Description: This plugin let you using wp_query to filter taxonomy,custom meta and post type as search result.
Version: 1.0.10
Author: TC 
Author URI: http://www.9-sec.com/
*/
if ( ! defined( 'UWPQSFBASE' ) )
 define( 'UWPQSFBASE', untrailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
if ( ! defined( 'UADDFORMURL' ) )
 define( 'UADDFORMURL', admin_url('admin.php?page=uwpqsfform') );

if(!class_exists('ulitmatewpsf')){
include_once('classes/uwpqsf-base-class.php');
include_once('admin/list-from-class.php'); 
include_once('classes/uwpqsf-front-class.php');
include_once('classes/uwpqsf-process-class.php');
include_once('functions.php');
class ulitmatewpsf{
  const post_type = 'uwpqsf';

  function __construct(){
  add_action( 'init' , array( $this,'uwpqsf_setting' ) );
  add_action('admin_menu', array($this,'uwpqsf_menu')); 
  //save form
   add_action('admin_init', array($this,'uwpqsf_save_from'));
  // admin add taxonomy ajax
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_uwpqsfTaxo_ajax', array( $this,'uwpqsfTaxo_ajax') );  
  // admin add meta fields ajax
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_uwpqsfCmf_ajax', array( $this,'uwpqsfCmf_ajax') ); 
  //generate exlude terms
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_uwpqsfexclude_terms', array( $this,'uwpqsfexclude_terms') ); 
 }

  function uwpqsf_setting(){
 register_post_type( self::post_type, array(
   'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Ultimate WPQSF', 'UWPQSF' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Ultimate AWPSF', 'UWPQSF' ) ),
     'exclude_from_search'=>true,
   'publicly_queryable'=>false,
   'rewrite' => false,
   'query_var' => false ) );
 load_plugin_textdomain( 'UWPQSF', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang/' );
 add_shortcode('ULWPQSF', array($this, 'U_wpqsf_shortcode'));
 add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
  }  

  function uwpqsf_menu() {
      if(isset($_GET['page']) && isset($_GET['uformaction']) && $_GET['page'] == 'uwpqsfform' &&  $_GET['uformaction'] == 'edit'){
   if(isset($_GET['uformid']) && absint($_GET['uformid'])){
    $editmenu = __("Edit Form","UWPQSF");
    $title = __("Edit Ultimate WPQSF ","UWPQSF"); 
    }
        }
      $menutitle = isset($editmenu) ? $editmenu : __("Add Form","UWPQSF");
      $pagetitle = isset($title) ? $title : __("Add New Ultimate WPQSF ","UWPQSF"); 
    add_menu_page(__("Ultimate Query Search Filter","UWPQSF"),__("Ulitmate WPQSF","UWPQSF"),'manage_options','ultimatewpqsf', array($this,'Uwoqsf_page'));
   $plugin_page =  add_submenu_page( 'ultimatewpqsf', $pagetitle , $menutitle, 'manage_options', 'uwpqsfform', array($this,'add_new_form_callback') ); 
  
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-'.$plugin_page, array($this,'admin_uwpqsf_js'));
    add_action('admin_print_styles-'.$plugin_page, array($this,'admin_uwpqsf_css'));
 
  }

  function Uwoqsf_page(){
 global $uwqsfmain;
 $uwqsfmain = new Uwpqsf_Table;
 $uwqsfmain->prepare_items(); 
 $uddlink = add_query_arg(array('uformid' => 'new', 'uformaction' => 'new'), UADDFORMURL);
 echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"></div><h2>'.esc_html( __( 'Ultimate WP Query Search Filter', 'UWPQSF' ) ).'<a      href="'.$uddlink .'" class="add-new-h2">'.esc_html( __( 'Add New Search Form', 'UWPQSF' ) ).'</a></h2>'; 
 echo '<form method="post">'; $uwqsfmain->display();   
 echo '</form></div>'; 
  }
 
  function add_new_form_callback(){
 require_once UWPQSFBASE . '/admin/forms.php';
  }
 
  function admin_uwpqsf_js(){
 
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');
 wp_enqueue_script('js', plugins_url('admin/scripts/uadmin_awqsfjs.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
 wp_localize_script( 'ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); 
  } 

  function admin_uwpqsf_css(){
 wp_enqueue_style('uwpqsfcss', plugins_url('admin/scripts/admin_uwpqsf.css', __FILE__), '1.0', true);
  }

  function uwpqsfTaxo_ajax(){
 include 'admin/ajax-add-taxo.php';
   }

  function uwpqsfCmf_ajax(){
 include 'admin/ajax-add-cmf.php';
  }   

  function uwpqsf_save_from(){
   if(isset($_POST['uwpqsfsub'])){

  if (! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'ultimate-wpqsf-edit') ) {
   $this->handle_error()->add('nonce', __("No naughty business here, dude", 'UWPQSF'));
   return; 
  }


  $postid =sanitize_text_field($_POST['uformid']);
  $themeoption = $cptarray = $taxoarray = $cmfarray =$relarray ='';
   if(!empty($_POST['uwpname']['cpt'])){
    foreach($_POST['uwpname']['cpt'] as $cv){
      $cptarray[] = sanitize_text_field($cv);
     
    }
   }
   if(isset($_POST['uwpname']['taxo'])){
    
    foreach($_POST['uwpname']['taxo'] as $tv){
     $taxoarray[]=array(
       'taxname' => sanitize_text_field($tv['taxname']),
       'taxlabel'=> sanitize_text_field($tv['taxlabel']),
       'taxall' => sanitize_text_field($tv['taxall']),
       'hide' => sanitize_text_field($tv['hide']),
       'exc' => sanitize_text_field($tv['exc']),
       'type' => sanitize_text_field($tv['type']),
       'operator' => sanitize_text_field($tv['operator']),
       'exsearch' => sanitize_text_field($tv['exsearch']),
      );
     
     
     }
   }

   if(isset($_POST['uwpname']['cmf'])){
    foreach($_POST['uwpname']['cmf'] as $cv){
      $cmfarray[] = array(
       'metakey' => sanitize_text_field($cv['metakey']),
       'label' => sanitize_text_field($cv['label']),
       'all' => sanitize_text_field($cv['all']),
       'compare' => wp_filter_nohtml_kses( stripslashes($cv['compare'])),
       'type' => sanitize_text_field($cv['type']),
       'opt' => sanitize_text_field($cv['opt'])
      );
     
     }
   }

          if(isset($_POST['uwpname']['rel'])){
    foreach($_POST['uwpname']['rel'] as $rv){
      $relarray[] = array(
       'method'=> isset($rv['method']) ? sanitize_text_field($rv['method']) : '',
       'tax'=> isset($rv['tax']) ? sanitize_text_field($rv['tax']) : '',
       'cmf'=> isset($rv['cmf']) ? sanitize_text_field($rv['cmf']) : '',
       'strchk'=> isset($rv['strchk']) ? sanitize_text_field($rv['strchk']) : '',
       'strlabel'=> isset($rv['strlabel']) ? $rv['strlabel'] : '',
       'smetekey'=> isset($rv['smetekey']) ? $rv['smetekey'] :'',
       'otype'=> isset($rv['otype']) ? sanitize_text_field($rv['otype']) : '',
       'sorder'=> isset($rv['sorder']) ? sanitize_text_field($rv['sorder']) : '',
       'button'=> isset($rv['button']) ? $rv['button'] : '',
       'resultc'=> isset($rv['resultc']) ? $rv['resultc'] : '',
       'div'=> isset($rv['div']) ? $rv['div'] : '',
       'snf'=> isset($rv['snf']) ? $rv['snf'] : '',
      );
     }
   }
     
   if(isset($_POST['themeopt'])){
    $themeoption = $_POST['themeopt'];
   }   
  
   if($postid == 'new'){

    $post_information = array(
     'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['ftitle']) ,
     'post_type' => self::post_type,
     'post_status' => 'publish'
     );
    $newform_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);
    if(empty($newform_id)){
     $this->handle_error()->add('insert', __("Error! Try to create again.", 'UWPQSF'));
     return; 
     
    }
    if(!empty($cptarray) ){
    update_post_meta($newform_id, 'uwpqsf-cpt', $cptarray);}
    if(!empty($taxoarray)){
    update_post_meta($newform_id, 'uwpqsf-taxo', $taxoarray);}
    if(!empty($cmfarray)){
    update_post_meta($newform_id, 'uwpqsf-cmf', $cmfarray);}
    if(!empty($relarray)){
    update_post_meta($newform_id, 'uwpqsf-option', $relarray);}
    if(!empty($themeoption)){
    update_post_meta($newform_id, 'uwpqsf-theme', $themeoption);}
    do_action('saving_uwpqsf_form', $_POST);
        
    $returnlink = add_query_arg(array('uformid' => $newform_id, 'uformaction' => 'edit','status'=>'success'), UADDFORMURL);
    wp_redirect( $returnlink ); exit;
  }//end add new


  if($postid != 'new' && absint($postid) ){

    $updateform = array();
     $updateform['ID'] = $postid ;
     $updateform['post_title'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ftitle']);
   $update = wp_update_post( $updateform );
   if(empty($update)){
     $this->handle_error()->add('update', __("Error! Something wrong when updating your setting.", 'UWPQSF'));
     return; 
     
    }
   
    $oldcpt = get_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-cpt', true);
    $oldtaxo = get_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-taxo', true);
    $oldcmf = get_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-cmf', true); 
    $oldrel = get_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-option', true);
    $oldthemeopt = get_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-theme', true);
    
    $newcpt = !empty($cptarray) ? $cptarray : '';
    $newtaxo = !empty($taxoarray) ? $taxoarray : '';
    $newcmf = !empty($cmfarray) ? $cmfarray : '';
    $newrel = !empty($relarray) ? $relarray : '';
    $newthemeopt = !empty($themeoption) ? $themeoption : '';

    if (empty($newcpt)) {
    delete_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-cpt', $oldcpt); 
    
    } elseif($oldcpt != $newcpt) {
    update_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-cpt', $newcpt);
    }
    
    if (empty($newtaxo)) {
    delete_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-taxo', $oldtaxo);
    
    } elseif($newtaxo != $oldtaxo) {
    update_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-taxo', $newtaxo);
    }

    if (empty($newcmf)) {
    delete_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-cmf', $oldcmf);
    } elseif ($newcmf != $oldcmf) {
    update_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-cmf', $newcmf);
    } 
    
    
    if (empty($newrel)) {
    delete_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-option', $oldrel);
    } elseif ($newrel != $oldrel) {
    update_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-option', $newrel);
    }
    
    if($newthemeopt != $oldthemeopt) {
    update_post_meta($postid, 'uwpqsf-theme', $newthemeopt);
    }
    
    do_action('saving_uwpqsf_form', $_POST);
    
    $returnlink = add_query_arg(array('uformid' => $postid, 'uformaction' => 'edit','status'=>'updated'), UADDFORMURL);
    wp_redirect( $returnlink ); exit;

   
   }//end update
  
    }//end submit
  

  }

  function U_wpqsf_shortcode($atts){
 extract(shortcode_atts(array('id' => false, 'formtitle' =>1, 'button' => 1,'divclass' => '', 'infinite'=>'', 'text_position' => 'bottom', 'lang'=>''), $atts));
 //wpml
 if(function_exists('icl_object_id') && $lang) {
  $current_language = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
  $languages = explode(' ',$lang);
  foreach($languages as $k => $v){
   $getLang = explode('=',$v);
   if(trim($getLang[0]) == trim($current_language)){
    $id = $getLang[1]; 
    break;   
   }
  } 
  
 }
 
 if($id)
 {
   ob_start();
   $output = include UWPQSFBASE . '/html/searchform.php';
   $output = ob_get_clean();
   return $output;
 }
 else{
  echo 'no form added.';
 }
  } 
  
  function uwpqsfexclude_terms(){
   $cutax   = $_POST['cutax'];
   $exterms = $_POST['exterms'];
   $ediv = '.'.$_POST['ediv'];
   $edis = array();
   if(!empty($exterms)){
    $edis = explode(",",  $exterms );
   }
   echo '<h3>'.__('Selected Taxonomy : '.$cutax,"UWPQSF").'</h3><br>';
  
   if(!empty($cutax)){
    $gterms = get_terms( $cutax , array('hide_empty' => 0 ) );
    foreach($gterms as $gterm){
     echo '<label><input ',in_array($gterm->term_id,$edis) ? 'checked = "checked" ' : '',' type="checkbox" class="exids" value="'.$gterm->term_id.'">'.$gterm->name.'</label>';
    }
   }else{
      if(empty($cutax)){
      echo __("Please Select a taxonomy first","UWPQSF");}
      else{ 
      echo __("No term found in this taxonomy ","UWPQSF");
    }
    }
 echo '<input type="hidden" id="ediv" value="'.$ediv.'">';  
 
   exit; 
  } 

}//end of class

}//end of check class
global $uwpqsf;
$uwpqsf = new ulitmatewpsf();
?>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
  $('body').on('click','.usearchbtn', function(e) {
   process_data($(this));
   return false;
  });
 
  $('body').on('click','.upagievent', function(e) {
   var pagenumber =  $(this).attr('id');
   var formid = $('#curuform').val();
   upagi_ajax(pagenumber, formid);
   return false;
  });

  $('body').on('keypress','.uwpqsftext',function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
                if (!form) {
                    id = $(this);
                }else{
                    var id = $('#'+form); 
                }
                process_data(id);     
    }
  });
  
  window.process_data = function ($obj) {
   var ajxdiv = $obj.closest("form").find("#uajaxdiv").val(); 
   var res = {loader:$('<div />',{'class':'umloading'}),container : $(''+ajxdiv+'')};
            var formid = $obj.parent().parent().attr('id'); console.log(formid);
   var getdata = $obj.closest("form").serialize();
   var pagenum = '1';
  
   jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'POST',  
     url: ajax.url,
     data: ({action : 'uwpqsf_ajax',getdata:getdata, pagenum:pagenum }),
     beforeSend:function() {$(''+ajxdiv+'').empty();res.container.append(res.loader);$obj.closest("form").find('input, textarea, button, select').attr("disabled", true);},
     success: function(html) {
     res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
      $(''+ajxdiv+'').html(html);
      $obj.closest("form").find('input, textarea, button, select').attr("disabled", false);
    
     }
     });
   
  } 
  
  window.upagi_ajax = function (pagenum, formid) {
   var ajxdiv = $(''+formid+'').find("#uajaxdiv").val(); 
   var res = {loader:$('<div />',{'class':'umloading'}),container : $(''+ajxdiv+'')};
   var getdata = $(''+formid+'').serialize();
  
   jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'POST',  
     url: ajax.url,
     data: ({action : 'uwpqsf_ajax',getdata:getdata, pagenum:pagenum }),
     beforeSend:function() {$(''+ajxdiv+'').empty(); res.container.append(res.loader);},
     success: function(html) {
      res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
      $(''+ajxdiv+'').html(html);
    
    //res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
     }
     });
  }
  
  $('body').on('click', '.chktaxoall, .chkcmfall',function () {
  
     $(this).closest('.togglecheck').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  
         });



});//end of script
```

```css
<?php
if(!class_exists('uwpqsfront')){
  class uwpqsfront{
  
  function output_formtaxo_fields($type,$exc,$hide,$taxname,$taxlabel,$taxall,$opt,$c,$defaultclass,$formid,$divclass){
  $eid = explode(",", $exc);
  $args = array('hide_empty'=>$hide,'exclude'=>$eid ); 
  $taxoargs = apply_filters('uwpqsf_taxonomy_arg',$args,$taxname,$formid);
         $terms = get_terms($taxname,$taxoargs);
      $count = count($terms);
   if($type == 'dropdown'){
   $html  = '<div class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.'" id="tax-select-'.$c.'"><span class="taxolabel-'.$c.'">'.$taxlabel.'</span>';
   $html .= '<input  type="hidden" name="taxo['.$c.'][name]" value="'.$taxname.'">';
   $html .= '<input  type="hidden" name="taxo['.$c.'][opt]" value="'.$opt.'">';
   $html .=  '<select id="tdp-'.$c.'" class="tdp-class-'.$c.'" name="taxo['.$c.'][term]">'; 
   if(!empty($taxall)){
    $html .= '<option selected value="uwpqsftaxoall">'.$taxall.'</option>';
   }
     if ( $count > 0 ){
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      $selected = (isset($_GET['taxo'][$c]['term']) && $_GET['taxo'][$c]['term'] == $term->slug) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';        
     $html .= '<option value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$selected.'>'.$term->name.'</option>';}
   }    
   $html .= '</select>';
   $html .= '</div>';
   return  apply_filters( 'uwpqsf_tax_field_dropdown', $html ,$type,$exc,$hide,$taxname,$taxlabel,$taxall,$opt,$c,$defaultclass,$formid,$divclass);
  }
  if($type == 'checkbox'){
    if ( $count > 0 ){
    $html  = '<div class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.' togglecheck" id="tax-check-'.$c.'"><span  class="taxolabel-'.$c.'">'.$taxlabel.'</span >';
    $html .= '<input  type="hidden" name="taxo['.$c.'][name]" value="'.$taxname.'">';
    $html .= '<input  type="hidden" name="taxo['.$c.'][opt]" value="'.$opt.'">';
    if(!empty($taxall)){
    $checkall = (isset($_GET['taxo'][$c]['call']) && $_GET['taxo'][$c]['call'] == '1'  ) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; 
    $html .= '<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-'.$c.'-0" class="tchkb-'.$c.' chktaxoall" name="taxo['.$c.'][call]"  value="1" '.$checkall.'>'.$taxall.'</label>';
    }
    $i = 1;
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $value = $term->slug;
    $checked = (isset($_GET['taxo'][$c]['term']) && in_array($value, $_GET['taxo'][$c]['term'])) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    $html .= '<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-'.$c.'-'.$i.'" class="tchkb-'.$c.'" name="taxo['.$c.'][term][]" value="'.$value.'" '.$checked.'>'.$term->name.'</label>';
    $i++;
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    return  apply_filters( 'uwpqsf_tax_field_checkbox', $html ,$type,$exc,$hide,$taxname,$taxlabel,$taxall,$opt,$c,$defaultclass,$formid,$divclass);
   }
    
  }
  if($type == 'radio'){
    if ( $count > 0 ){
    $html  = '<div class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.'" id="tax-radio-'.$c.'"><span class="taxolabel-'.$c.'">'.$taxlabel.'</span>';
    $html .= '<input  type="hidden" name="taxo['.$c.'][name]" value="'.$taxname.'">';
    $html .= '<input  type="hidden" name="taxo['.$c.'][opt]" value="'.$opt.'">';
    if(!empty($taxall)){
    $html .= '<label><input type="radio" id="tradio-'.$c.'-0" class="tradio-'.$c.'" name="taxo['.$c.'][term]" value="uwpqsftaxoall">'.$taxall.'</label>';
    }
    $n = 1;
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       
    $checked = (isset($_GET['taxo'][$c]['term']) && $_GET['taxo'][$c]['term'] == $term->slug) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    $html .= '<label><input type="radio" id="tradio-'.$c.'-'.$n.'" class="tradio-'.$c.'" name="taxo['.$c.'][term]" value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$checked.'>'.$term->name.'</label>';
    $n++;
   }

    
    $html .= '</div>';
    return  apply_filters( 'uwpqsf_tax_field_radio', $html ,$type,$exc,$hide,$taxname,$taxlabel,$taxall,$opt,$c,$defaultclass,$formid,$divclass);
   }
    
  }
   if($type != 'dropdown' or $type != 'checkbox' or $type != 'radio') {
   return apply_filters( 'uwpqsf_addtax_field_'.$type.'', $type,$exc,$hide,$taxname,$taxlabel,$taxall,$opt,$c,$defaultclass,$formid,$divclass);
 
  }
  
  
  }

   function output_formcmf_fields($type,$metakey,$compare,$metaval,$label,$all,$i,$defaultclass,$id,$divclass ){
   $opts = explode("|", $metaval);
  
   if($type == 'dropdown'){
    $html = '<div class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.'" id="cmf-select'.$i.'"><span class="cmflabel-'.$i.'">'.$label.'</span>';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="cmf['.$i.'][metakey]" value="'.$metakey.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="cmf['.$i.'][compare]" value="'.$compare.'">';
    $html .=  '<select id="cmfdp-'.$i.'" class="cmfdp-class-'.$i.'" name="cmf['.$i.'][value]">'; 
    if(!empty($all)){
    $html .= '<option value="uwpqsfcmfall">'.$all.'</option>';
    }
    
     foreach ( $opts as $opt ) {
       $val = explode('::',$opt);
       $selected = (isset($_GET['cmf'][$i]['value']) && $_GET['cmf'][$i]['value'] == $val[0]) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; 
       $html .= '<option value="'.$val[0].'" '.$selected.'>'.$val[1].'</option>';
     }
    $html .= '</select>';
    $html .= '</div>';
    
    return  apply_filters( 'uwpqsf_cmf_field_dropdown', $html,$type,$metakey,$compare,$metaval,$label,$all,$i,$defaultclass,$id,$divclass);
   
   }
   if($type == 'checkbox'){
        $html  = '<div class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.' togglecheck" id="cmf-check-'.$i.'"><span class="cmflabel-'.$i.'">'.$label.'</span>';
     $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="cmf['.$i.'][metakey]" value="'.$metakey.'">';
     $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="cmf['.$i.'][compare]" value="'.$compare.'">';
    if(!empty($all)){
     $checkall = (isset($_GET['cmf'][$i]['call']) && $_GET['cmf'][$i]['call'] == '1'  ) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; 
     $html .= '<label><input type="checkbox" id="cmf-'.$i.'-0" class="cmf-'.$i.' chkcmfall" name="cmf['.$i.'][call]"  value="1" '.$checkall.'>'.$all.'</label>';
    }
    $c = 1;
    foreach ( $opts as $opt ) {
            $val = explode('::',$opt);
     $checked = (isset($_GET['cmf'][$i]['value']) && in_array($val[0],$_GET['cmf'][$i]['value']) ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
            $html .= '<label><input type="checkbox" id="cmf-'.$i.'-'.$c.'" class="cmf-'.$i.'" name="cmf['.$i.'][value][]" value="'.$val[0].'" '.$checked.'>'.$val[1].'</label>';
      $c++;
     }
     $html .= '</div>';
    
    return  apply_filters( 'uwpqsf_cmf_field_checkbox', $html,$type,$metakey,$compare,$metaval,$label,$all,$i,$defaultclass,$id,$divclass);
   } 
   if($type == 'radio'){
       $html  = '<div class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.'" id="cmf-radio-'.$i.'"><span class="cmflabel-'.$i.'">'.$label.'</span>';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="cmf['.$i.'][metakey]" value="'.$metakey.'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="cmf['.$i.'][compare]" value="'.$compare.'">';
   if(!empty($all)){
               $html .= '<label><input type="radio" id="cmf-'.$i.'-0" class="cmf-'.$i.'" name="cmf['.$i.'][value]" value="uwpqsfcmfall">'.$all.'</label>';
   }
      $n = 1;
   foreach ( $opts as $opt ) {
    $val = explode('::',$opt);
    $checked = (isset($_GET['cmf'][$i]['value']) && $_GET['cmf'][$i]['value'] == $val[0]) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    $html .= '<label><input type="radio" id="cmf-'.$i.'-'.$n.'" class="cmf-'.$i.'" name="cmf['.$i.'][value]" value="'.$val[0].'" '.$checked.'>'.$val[1].'</label>';
    $n++;
   } 
    $html .= '</div>';
    
    return  apply_filters( 'uwpqsf_cmf_field_radio', $html,$type,$metakey,$compare,$metaval,$label,$all,$i,$defaultclass,$id,$divclass);
   }
  if($type != 'dropdown' or $type != 'checkbox' or $type != 'radio') {
   return apply_filters( 'uwpqsf_addcmf_field_'.$type.'', $type,$metakey,$compare,$metaval,$label,$all,$i,$defaultclass,$id,$divclass);
 
  }   
   
   }  
 
  }//end class
}//end check class
;?>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
$nonce = wp_create_nonce  ('uwpsfsearch');
$taxo = get_post_meta($id, 'uwpqsf-taxo', true);
$cmf = get_post_meta($id, 'uwpqsf-cmf', true);
$options = get_post_meta($id, 'uwpqsf-option', true);
$css = get_post_meta($id, 'uwpqsf-theme', true);
$excss = explode('|', $css);
$divid = ($excss[2]) ? $excss[2] : 'uwpqsf_id';
$defaultclass = ($excss[3]) ? $excss[3] : 'uwpqsf_class';

if($options[0]['method'] == '1'){
 $hidden = '<input type="hidden" id="uajaxdiv" value="'.$options[0]['div'].'">';
 $btype = 'button';
 $method = '';
 $bclass = 'usearchbtn';
 $auto = true;
}else{
  $hidden = '<input type="hidden" name="s" value="uwpsfsearchtrg" />';
 $btype = 'submit';
 $method = 'method="get" action="'.home_url( '/' ).'"';
 $bclass ='';
 $auto = false;
}




$fields = new uwpqsfront();

$html = '<div id="'.$divid.'">';
$html .= '<form id="uwpqsffrom_'.$id.'" '.$method.'>';
if($formtitle){
 $html .= '<div class="uform_title">'.get_the_title($id).'</div>';
}
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="unonce" value="'.$nonce.'" /><input type="hidden" name="uformid" value="'.$id.'">';

$html .= $hidden;

ob_start(); 
$html .= do_action( 'uwpqsf_form_top', $atts);
$html .= ob_get_clean();

if(isset($options[0]['strchk']) && ($options[0]['strchk'] == '1') && $text_position =="top"){
  $stext  = '<div class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.'"><label class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.'-keyword">'.$options[0]['strlabel'].'</label>';
  $oldvalue = (isset($_GET['skeyword'])) ? $_GET['skeyword'] : '';
  $stext .= '<input id="'.$divid.'_key" type="text" name="skeyword" class="uwpqsftext" value="'.$oldvalue.'" />';
        $stext .= '</div>';
        $textsearch =  apply_filters('uwpqsf_string_search',$stext, $id,$divid,$defaultclass,$divclass,$options);
        $html .= $textsearch;
}

if(!empty($taxo)){
 $c = 0;
 foreach($taxo as $k => $v){
  $eid = explode(",", $v['exc']);
  $args = array('hide_empty'=>$v['hide'],'exclude'=>$eid );
        $terms = get_terms($v['taxname'],$args);
      $count = count($terms);
  $html .= $fields->output_formtaxo_fields($v['type'],$v['exc'],$v['hide'],$v['taxname'],$v['taxlabel'],$v['taxall'],$v['operator'],$c,$defaultclass,$id,$divclass );

 $c++;
  }
}

ob_start(); 
do_action( 'uwpqsf_form_mid', $atts);
$html .= ob_get_clean();

if(!empty($cmf)){
   $i=0;
    foreach($cmf as $k => $v){
  if(isset($v['type'])){
   $html .= $fields->output_formcmf_fields($v['type'],$v['metakey'],$v['compare'],$v['opt'],$v['label'],$v['all'],$i,$defaultclass,$id,$divclass );
   $i++;
    }
 }
}

if(isset($options[0]['strchk']) && ($options[0]['strchk'] == '1') && $text_position =="bottom"){
  $stext  = '<div class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.'"><label class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.'-keyword">'.$options[0]['strlabel'].'</label>';
  $oldvalue = (isset($_GET['skeyword'])) ? $_GET['skeyword'] : '';
  $stext .= '<input id="'.$divid.'_key" type="text" name="skeyword" class="uwpqsftext" value="'.$oldvalue.'" />';
        $stext .= '</div>';
        $textsearch =  apply_filters('uwpqsf_string_search',$stext, $id,$divid,$defaultclass,$divclass,$options);
        $html .= $textsearch;
}
ob_start(); 
do_action( 'uwpqsf_form_bottom' , $atts);
$html .= ob_get_clean();

if($button && $button == '1'){
$wrapper = '<div class="'.$defaultclass.' '.$divclass.' uwpqsf_submit" id="uwpqsf_btn">';
$wrapper .= '<input type="'.$btype.'" id="'.$divid.'_btn" value="'.$options[0]['button'].'" alt="[Submit]" class="usfbtn '.$bclass.'" /></div>';
$btn = apply_filters('uwpsqf_form_btn', $wrapper, $id,$divclass,$defaultclass,$divid,$options[0]['button'] );
$html .= $btn;
}elseif($button == '0'){
 if($auto){
 $form = '"#uwpqsffrom_'.$id.'"';
 ob_start(); 
  ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var formid = <?php echo $form; ?>;
 $(formid).find('input, textarea, button, select').change(function(){ 
  process_data($(this)); 
  
  })
      ;})</script>
  <?php
    $html .= ob_get_clean();
 }
}
if(function_exists('icl_object_id') && $lang) {
 $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="'.$current_language.'"/>';
}
$html .= '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
$html .= '</form>';//end form
$html .= '</div>'; //end div
echo $html;
;?>
```

Comment: Sem ver o html e o resto do código é difícil respnder... mas veja que aqui `$(''+ajxdiv+'').html(html);` você está substituindo todo o conteúdo do elemento.

Comment: cria uma div separada onde vai ser colocado o loader e o resultado, sem precisar apagar o formulario

Comment: é que na verdade isso é um Plugin, pelo que eu procurei nos arquivos, esse é o que faz a transição do conteúdo, mas posso postar mais partes do código caso vocês precisem